# How do we argue that there are only integer-spaced $m$ values for angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I am following the usual development using ladder operators (in Ballentine Chapter 7) for the angular momentum spectrum (for the joint eigenbasis $|j,m \rangle$ of $J^2$ and $J_z$) and I am satisfied with the logic up to the point where we have demonstrated the existence of a maximum and minimum value for $m$ (given fixed $j$); namely, $m_{max} = j$ and $m_{min} = -j$.

I cannot convince myself of the next step though. Ballentine states without proof that

> We have thus shown the existence of a set of eigenvectors corresponding to integer spaced $m$ values in the range $−j \leq m \leq j$.

I am not sure I agree though. Up to this point in the argument, we have merely shown that $m$ obeys $−j \leq m \leq j$ and, further, that it is possible to add or subtract one from $m$ and still obtain a valid eigenstate as long as we remain within those bounds. But why should only integer-spaced $m$ be admissible? I recall hearing hazy arguments to the effect that, if not, then one could use the raising operator over and over and so obtain some $m$ violating $−j \leq m \leq j$. But why must this be so? We simply need to require (for example) that if $j-1 < m \leq j$, then $J_+|j,m\rangle = 0$ (i.e. just as with $|j,j\rangle$). Can someone explain the general argument leading to only integer-spaced values between $-j$ and $j$ being allowed?

This seems to me a requirement in order to assert that $j - (-j) \in \mathbb{N}$ so that one obtains the usual $j = k/2$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ condition on allowed values of the angular momentum.

Comment: Isn't the argument already covering that $\forall m\in(j-1,j)\qquad J_+\left|j,m\right>\neq0$? The hazy argument is just applying the ladder operators enough to reduce to this critical strip, as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: Quoting Ballentine, the argument only gives that "Therefore, either $J+|j,m⟩$ is an eigenvector of $J_z$ with the raised eigenvalue $(m + 1)$, or $J_+|j,m⟩ = 0$". So nothing says that $J_+|j,m⟩ \neq 0$ for $\forall m\in(j-1,j)$ as far as I can tell @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: I didn't bring my copy of Ballentine overseas with me. I think the wonderful book should not have made such a mistake. I'm sorry I cannot be of much more help.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm not sure if it's a mistake at all or if I'm simply not reading closely enough. At any rate, thank you as always for your help nevertheless!

Comment: $m_j=m_l+m_s$,  $j$ can be  half-integer or integer. As the difference between two spin quantum numbers $|m_s'-m_s| \in \mathbf{N}$ is integer and the same is trivial for the angular momentum quantum number  $|m_l'-m_l| \in \mathbf{N}$, therefore $|m_j'-m_j| \in \mathbf{N}$.

Comment: @M06-2x Are you saying that we can only establish this by appealing to something from outside the usual ladder argument?

Comment: It's easy to show that, if $m$ is an eigenvalue, then so is $-m$.  Given that $m$ and $-m$ must differ by an integer number of steps, the result follows.  The more complete argument is made in Gordon Baym's book on Quantum Mechanics

Comment: @EE18 For the ladder argument $J_\pm=S_\pm + L_\pm$, we can deduce easily that $J_\pm$ leads to $j\pm1$, therefore the eigenvectors are separated by integer numbers.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I am being a bit pedantic, but " if  is an eigenvalue, then so is −" does not (seem to me to?) establish that $m$ is an integer or half-integer. We could imagine that these were each on "separate ladders", as it were. I will take a look at Baym's book though, thank you.

Comment: @EE18.  Yes.  If you know they must be separated by an integer number, then $m$ must be integer or half integer, *v.g* if $m=1/3$ then $m'=-1/3$ then $m'-m=2/3$ is not an integer.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm saying that that supposes you can reach $m$ from $-m$, and it's not clear to me a priori why that should be the case.

Comment: @EE18 ok then the answer you want can be found in the Lie algebraic structure of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at the formulas (7.8 - 7.10). If you omit the words "maximum value of $m$", then these formulas simply demonstrate that for any state $|\beta, j\rangle$ such that
$$
J_{+}|\beta, j\rangle = 0 \quad (7.8)
$$
the following condition must be met
$$
\beta = j(j+1).\quad (7.10)
$$
If you have two different states sattisfiying (7.8), $|\beta, j_1\rangle$ and $|\beta, j_2\rangle$, it follows from (7.10) that the equality must hold
$$
j_1(j_1+1) = j_2(j_2+1).
$$
The last equality implies $j_1 = j_2$ or $j_1 + j_2 + 1 = 0$. I suppose there must be a way to show that $j_1 = j_2$. For example, we can similarly consider the situation with the minimum value of $m$.

Comment: Lovely, thank you for that! I think with regard to excluding $j_1 + j_2 + 1 = 0$, we need simply observe that we have taken $j_i \geq 0$ (c.f. equation (7.4)).